# What is IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, illegalstateexception

I am trying to use the [following Fastload API](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20208JD.java.txt)

connection ... etc is perfect.

---

I know exactly where it fails

```
 ...........
 System.out.println(" Streaming " + dataFile);
 pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream, -1); // This line fails
 System.out.println("check the above line"); // This does not go to console
 ...........
```

Exception is

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Sample failed.`

`[ODBC Teradata Driver] Invalid precision: cbColDef value out of range`

---

Here is my table that I am trying to upload. It is a `.csv` format and when I open it via notepad it look like this

```
1,9,Win
2,9,Winc
3,9,Wi
```

Why do I get this exception? How can I improve it? As far as I understand the problem is `pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream, -1);` does not accept the dataset somehow and throw an exception

Comment: I usually throw an `IllegalStateException` whenever I catch something that "cannot possibly happen" and there is no other more-descriptive exception type that I can throw. For example, say I write code to display an image, and the image has a negative width - throwing anything else would be worse, so I can either write my own unchecked exception (recommended practice, but then you may consider making it a checked exception instead), or use the built-in `IllegalStateException` one.

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setAsciiStream%28int,%20java.io.InputStream,%20int%29, is it possible that the file length (-1) is causing this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Usually, [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) is used to indicate that "a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time." However, this doesn't look like a particularly typical use of it.

The code you've linked to shows that it can be thrown *within that code* at line 259 - but only after dumping a `SQLException` to standard output.

We can't tell what's wrong just from that exception - and better code would have used the original `SQLException` as a "cause" exception (or just let the original exception propagate up the stack) - but you should be able to see more details on standard output. Look at that information, and you should be able to see what caused the exception, and fix it.

Comment: what is a `standard output`?

Comment: @BoratSagddiev: As in `System.out` - the standard output stream from your process, usually writing to a console if there's one attached, or often captured as a log file in a server-side process. As we don't know how you're running the code, it's hard to tell you where to look.

Comment: I have edited the question. I know exactly where it fails. `pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream, -1);` does not execute

Comment: I don't think it is dumping an SQLexception simply because it fails earlier

Comment: @BoratSagddiev: That's where it *initially* throws a SQLException - which is caught lower down, dumped, and then an IllegalStateException is thrown. So you really *should* have the SQLException logged.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Is this a good or bad example of using IllegalStateException https://stackoverflow.com/a/42011744/3184475 ? Please advise. Thanks. Btw, I am not the OP. He is a just an imitator. I am the real borat.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev: Fairly reasonable IMO.

Answer (score 22):

IllegalStateException signals that method has been invoked at the wrong time. In the example below we can see that the `remove()` method is mutating an element while its iterator is in a loop (an illegal call), which Java catches and throws:

```
package com.concepttimes.java;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
 
public class IllegalStateExceptionDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List al = new ArrayList();
        al.add("Sachin");
        al.add("Rahul");
        al.add("saurav");
        Iterator itr = al.iterator();  
        while (itr.hasNext()) {           
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer to below link for more details.
http://www.elitmuszone.com/elitmus/illegalstateexception-in-java/

Comment: Nick You are wrong ! The above answer actually put it me in the right direction to solve similar problem in my code. You should not down vote answers only because they refer to old questions. This is most inappropriate and discouraging to new SO users.

Comment: This _was_ actually a great example of an appropriate us of `IllegalStateException`. I had to read it a bit closer to see that. @Nick needs to up his reading comprehension.

Answer (score 19):

**Illegal State Exception** is an Unchecked exception.

It indicate that method has been invoked at wrong time.

example:

```
Thread t = new Thread();
t.start();
//
//
t.start();
```

output:

```
Runtime Excpetion: IllegalThreadStateException
```

We cant start the Thread again, it will throw IllegalStateException.