# How to provide correct arguments to setAsciiStream method?

Tags: java, ascii

This is my **FULL** test code with the main method:

```
public class TestSetAscii {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException {
        String dataFile = "FastLoad1.csv";
        String insertTable = "INSERT INTO " + "myTableName" + " VALUES(?,?,?)";
        Connection conStd = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:xxxxx", "xxxxxx", "xxxxx");
        InputStream dataStream = new FileInputStream(new File(dataFile));
        PreparedStatement pstmtFld  = conStd.prepareStatement(insertTable);
            // Until this line everything is awesome

        pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream, -1); // This line fails
        System.out.println("works");
    }
}
```

I get the "cbColDef value out of range" error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Invalid precision: cbColDef value out of range
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLBindInParameterAtExec(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setAsciiStream(Unknown Source)
    at file.TestSetAscii.main(TestSetAscii.java:21)
```

Here is the link to my [FastLoad1.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/FastLoad1.csv) file. I guess that `setAsciiStream` fails because of the [FastLoad1.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/FastLoad1.csv) file , but I am not sure

*(In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169127/what-is-illegalstateexception?noredirect=1#comment30067341_20169127) I was not able to narrow down the problem that I had. Now I have shortened the code.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would depend on the table schema, but the third parameter of     setAsciiStream is length.
So

```
pstmtFld.setAsciiStream(1, dataStream, 4);
```

would work for a field of length 4 bytes.

But I dont think it would work as you expect it in the code. For each bind you should have separate stream.

This function setAsciiStream() is designed to be used for large data values BLOBS or long VARCHARS. It is not designed to read csv file line by line and split them into separate values.

Basicly it just binds one of the question marks with the inputStream.

After looking into the provided example it looks like teradata could handle csv but you have to explicitly tell that with:

```
String urlFld = "jdbc:teradata://whomooz/TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8,TYPE=FASTLOADCSV";
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. This actually works. But I thought that "-1" would imply a field of any length (unlimited). how come "-1" does not work

Comment: When you say "bind" do you mean column? The question mark of the prepared statement? In here http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20208JD.java.txt there is only one stream

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I feel that this info can be valuable to those navigating fast load via JDBC for the first time.

This code will get the full stack trace and is very helpful for diagnosing problems with fast load:

```
catch (SQLException ex){
    for ( ; ex != null ; ex = ex.getNextException ())
        ex.printStackTrace () ;
}
```

In the case of the code above, it works if you specify TYPE=FASTLOADCSV in the connection string, but when run multiple times will fail due to the creation of the error tables _ERR_1 and _ERR_2. Drop these tables and clear out the destination tables to run again.