# it appears that an activity in a different package is registered for that scheme instead

Tags: android, dropbox

I dont seem to understand this error. Please, any help will be appreciated.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: com.example.root.filesactivity, PID: 28319
                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: There must be a com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity within your app's package registered for your URI scheme (db-srlvvanpolzcks2). However, it appears that an activity in a different package is registered for that scheme instead. If you have multiple apps that all want to use the same accesstoken pair, designate one of them to do authentication and have the other apps launch it and then retrieve the token pair from it.
                          at com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity.checkAppBeforeAuth(AuthActivity.java:319)
                          at com.dropbox.core.android.Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(Auth.java:67)
                          at com.dropbox.core.android.Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(Auth.java:27)
                          at com.dropbox.core.android.Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(Auth.java:19)
                          at com.example.root.filesactivity.UserActivity$1.onClick(UserActivity.java:36)
                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5675)
                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22641)
                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6285)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
    Application terminated.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169127/what-is-illegalstateexception

Comment: can you provide more details about this error, i.e where, when, how does it occur on your code?

Comment: ok, so i am trying to connect my app to dropbox and i was able to this with the help of someone here. now when i run the app and i click the log in button the app just terminates. so i checked in the run tab on my android studio and that was the error message. this happens only when i click on the login button but during the gradle build i get 0 errors.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've registered that URL scheme [for a different package than the one you're starting the app authorization flow](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/c710ef80f1c2700031baad7c615dc9934162c090/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/android/AuthActivity.java#L312). Make sure you register it in your AndroidManifest.xml under the same package. There's [an example here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L33).