# Casting audio with local server socket

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to fix an existing project which is casting video and audio to the web. 
I need to create local socket:

```
socketId = "my.application.media." + suffix + "-" + new 
Random().nextInt();
localServerSocket = new LocalServerSocket(socketId);

receiver = new LocalSocket();
receiver.connect(new LocalSocketAddress(socketId));
receiver.setReceiveBufferSize(SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE);
receiver.setSendBufferSize(SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE);

sender = localServerSocket.accept();
sender.setReceiveBufferSize(SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE);
sender.setSendBufferSize(SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

and creating media recorder:

```
mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate((int) 7.95 * 1024);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(sender.getFileDescriptor());

mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```

But I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException` after calling `start` on `mMediaRecorder`. What am I missing? When I'm not using  `sender.getFileDescriptor()` everything is working correctly so probably that's the problem. I know that there are many libraries which are providing this functionality but I prefer to fix this one. Casting the only video is working correctly and the only problem is with the audio. Thanks a lot for help.
Order of executed methods:
added logs to check the order of methods and thread:

```
creating sockets: Socket opening thread
creating receiver: Socket opening thread
creating sender: Socket opening thread
setting audio source: Socket opening thread
setting properties: Socket opening thread
creating file descriptor: Socket opening thread
preparing media recorder: Socket opening thread
starting media recorder: Socket opening thread
```

I found that I'm also receiving errors:

```
2019-02-13 18:15:49.701 6176-13833/? E/StagefrightRecorder: Output file descriptor is invalid
2019-02-13 18:15:49.701 7851-9780/my.application E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -38
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169127/what-is-illegalstateexception) this error `java.lang.IllegalStateException` occurring when

> a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time.

So with that in mind and with [this](http://androidsrc.net/android-client-server-using-sockets-client-implementation/) article in mind of how to use sockets, You should put your socket related staff inside `AsyncTask` (separated thread) and   use `try catch`.
[AsyncTask Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) , and [Socket Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket) if you want to expand your knowledge.

Comment: I forgot to mention that everything is running on a separated thread. The video is working properly so the architecture is done in the right way, the only problem is with the audio.

Comment: What kind of object is sender?

Comment: sender is the `LocalSocket` and everything is done in the try catch and the only error which I get is IllegalStateException without any explenation.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are trying to use `getFileDescriptor` before (or after if it close) `sender` have the data to pull it out. 
Try extracting the data at earlier location in the code to a variable and than use this variable instead.

Another possibility could be; [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder) documentation says

> You must specify a file descriptor that represents an actual file

so be sure that the type that `sender.getFileDescriptor()` return is the right type that `mMediaRecorder.setAudioChannels` can get.

Comment: I tried to create the variable and the use it but nothing changes. I also run `valid()` on tris FileDescription and it said `true` so the problem seems to be somewhere else. I've added logs to check the order of methods and thread - added in the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990816/mediarecorder-issue-on-android-lollipop