# How can I remove an item from a list while iterating over it?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
while (rrProcesses.size() > 0) {
        for (Process process : rrProcesses) {
            if (process.getBurstTime() <= quantum) {
                System.out.println("@t=" + clock + ", selected for " + process.getBurstTime() + " units");
                clock += process.getBurstTime();
                rrProcesses.remove(process);
            } else {
                System.out.println("@t=" + clock + ", selected for " + quantum + " units");
                clock += quantum;
                process.setBurstTime(process.burstTime - quantum);
            }

            if (processCounter != rrProcesses.size()) {
                System.out.println("@t=" + clock + ", context switch " + contextSwitch + " occurs");
                contextSwitch++;
                clock += latency;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am attempting to iterate over each object within my list, remove an item based on a conditional, and keep looping until all items are removed.

When I run this in intellij, I get the following err:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1013)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:967)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:224)
```

I searched the issue and found this solution. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18448699/8008686)

When I changed my code it became this:

```
Iterator<Process> iter = rrProcesses.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        for (Process process : rrProcesses) {
            if (process.getBurstTime() <= quantum) {
                System.out.println("@t=" + clock + ", selected for " + process.getBurstTime() + " units");
                clock += process.getBurstTime();
                iter.remove();
            } else {
                System.out.println("@t=" + clock + ", selected for " + quantum + " units");
                clock += quantum;
                process.setBurstTime(process.burstTime - quantum);
            }

            if (processCounter != rrProcesses.size()) {
                System.out.println("@t=" + clock + ", context switch " + contextSwitch + " occurs");
                contextSwitch++;
                clock += latency;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, now I am receiving the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:980)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:228)
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51365264/8008686) to the error but its honestly not clarifying anything for me. How is it possible for me to then remove the object from the List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have a `for` loop inside your iterator loop. Replace it with this:

```
Process process = iter.next();
```

Comment: Thank you, will check it when the timer clears.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to @shmosel s answer, you can also use a for loop that iterates over the iterator. With this, you can also remove the item in question.

Basically this is the same approach as yours (get iter, while iter.hasNext, iter.next) but I prefer this style, because it keeps all allocated variables inside the loop scope.

```
    for (final Iterator<Processes> iter = rrProcesses.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println("\t" + iter.next());
    }
```